# JSX.Element as props in interface TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have interface for component which should take a JSX.Element as prop, how can I normally do this? Now I use ReactNode, but when i try to display the icon it doesn't work

```
export interface firstLevelMenuItem {
  route: string;
  name: string;
  icon: ReactNode;
}
```

```
import { Courses, Books, Products, Services } from "@/components/UI";
const firstLevelMenu: firstLevelMenuItem[] = [
  {
    route: "courses",
    name: "Курсы",
    icon: Courses,
  },
];

const buildFirstLevel = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <>
        {firstLevelMenu &&
          firstLevelMenu.map((el) => (
            <div key={el.route}>
              <a href={`/${el.route}`}>
                <div
                  className={cn(styles.firstLevel, {
                    [styles.firstLevelActive]: el.id == firstCategory,
                  })}
                >
                  {el.icon} // doesn't show
                  <span>{el.name}</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          ))}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Example of icon component:

```
const Courses = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    // some svg
  );
};

export default Courses;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to render the function(?) `Courses`, or whatever it is. If you want to render it as a JSX element, you have to write it as a JSX element:

```js
const firstLevelMenu: firstLevelMenuItem[] = [
  {
    route: "courses",
    name: "Курсы",
    icon: <Courses />,
  },
];
```

Alternatively, render it as a JSX element in your render code:

```js
firstLevelMenu.map((el) => (
    const Icon = el.icon;
    <div key={el.route}>
        <a href={`/${el.route}`}>
        <div
            className={cn(styles.firstLevel, {
            [styles.firstLevelActive]: el.id == firstCategory,
            })}
        >
            <Icon />
            <span>{el.name}</span>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: Remember to mark the correct answer as the solution to your question